# Error when installing software and repository

Tags: 18.04, repository

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my laptop and have decided to use OBS to attempt to stream my screen to either Youtube or Twitch. I have looked into the official OBS installation guide and this is what it has told me to input intto the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install obs-studio
```

Although whenever I install the repositories, I try to install the OBS-studio application I receive this error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/obs-studio_23.2.1-0obsproject1~bionic_amd64.deb (--unpack):

trying to overwrite '/usr/share/obs/libobs/bicubic_scale.effect', which is also in package libobs0:amd64 21.0.2+dfsg1-1

dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:

/var/cache/apt/archives/obs-studio_23.2.1-0obsproject1~bionic_amd64.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The same error appears whenever I install the application first.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem you need to remove the problematic package with

```
sudo apt-get remove libobs0
```

or

```
sudo dpkg --purge libobs0
```

and then install needed package with

```
sudo apt-get install obs-studio
```